# Error for Querying JSON in Postgres: function json_extract_path_text(text, text) does not exist

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a view based on a query to a *text* column that contains JSON in the latest version (9.3.4) of Postgres, but I get an error that I have not been able to find any discussion about.

Let's assume the table is called *table1* and the particular column, *json_data*, has something like

```
{"item1": "value1", "item2": "value2", "item3": 3, "item4": 4, "item5": 5}
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
json_extract_path_text((table1.json_data)::text, 
('item1'::character varying)::text) AS item1
FROM
table1
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR:  function json_extract_path_text(text, text) does not exist
LINE 2: json_extract_path_text((table1.json_data)...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm lost on how to fix this. (Also, I have a similar view that works completely fine using the same syntax on a similar *text* column in the particular table.)

Comment: "the latest version" = "9.3" ? 9.4 beta?

Comment: I'm using the 9.3 version.

Comment: Thanks. What's "latest" now doesn't mean "latest" a year later when someone else reads the question & answers, after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since table1.json_data is already text you need to cast it to json. You also don't need to specify the table name because it is in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(json_data::json,'item1') AS item1 FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, you're casting the `json` input to `text`:

```
json_extract_path_text((table1.json_data)::text
```

don't do that.

```
SELECT 
    json_extract_path_text(
        table1.json_data,
        'item1'
    ) AS item1
FROM table1
```

Comment: I still get an error, though it's different: `ERROR: column table1.json_data does not exist`...

Comment: Well, there's no possible way I can help you with that, as you haven't shown your table definitions. The query works fine, as you can verify by putting a literal json value in place of `table1.json_data`.

Comment: Your question says "Let's assume the table is called `table1` and the particular column, `json_data`, has something like `{…json…}`". If `table1.json_data` does not exist, that's on you; this answer is correct.

Comment: how to put where clause if we want to retrieve row based on the matching of data from json_data like for case based on 'item 1'

Comment: @nikhil84 Please post a new question. Put a link in the new question back to this one for context if you want.